# How do I create a fake form with controls in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a function which receives a form and marks a control as dirty.

I can't figure out how to manually create an instance of a fake form to use as a substitute in a unit test.

```
markControlDirty(form: NgForm) {
  let firstControl = form.controls[Object.keys(form.controls)[0]];
  firstControl.markAsDirty();
}
```

I have tried the following snippet from another answer on this site, but it doesn't include any controls, so my code fails on `Object.keys(form.controls)` since `form.controls` is undefined:

```
let fakeForm = <NgForm> {
  value: {
    name: 'Hello',
    category: 'World'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `FormBuilder` to create a dummy form group from any object you wish.

Then, if you need to mock some behavior, jasmine provides `spyOnProperty` method which will allow you to mock the return of value/controls or any other readOnly property (which is very useful when dealing with forms).

https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/global.html#spyOnProperty

How I would create my dummy form:

```
const myModel = {
   name: 'Hello',
   category: 'World'
};
const fb = new FormBuilder();
const form = fb.group(myModel);
```

And then you can spy on anything you want thanks to spyOnProperty.

For instance:

```
spyOnProperty(form, 'valid', 'get').and.returnValue(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that solution doesn't give me an NgForm object, which is what I need. It is creating a FormGroup object.